# jsFiddle.net sudden problems: 'getCode is not a function'

Tags: jsfiddle

Is anyone else having problems with [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

When clicking button "run" nothing happens, firefox error log says: `this.editor.getCode is not a function`.
On "jsHint" (what's up with that, wasn't that jsLint last week and before?) I get: `Layout.editors.js.editor.getCode` is not a function.
Save button, same story.
Opening my saved projects gives (preview) output, but no visible html/css/javascript code.

Also, in html edit-field, closing-tags suddenly red (but not the `<` character)?
Documentation of js-fiddle also gives no clue.
Last saturday/sunday everything was still working 'normally'.

Does anyone know more? (their latest [blog](http://blog.jsfiddle.net/)-entry is from 29 june 2012 and their irc chat #jsfiddle on freenode is completely silent for the last four hours)

I did however (on the twitter-feed placed on their blog) see other some others with sudden problems in the last 12 hours.

Comment: @ChrisF: at the time of asking, I clearly wasn't the only one with this exact problem. Googling 'getCode is not a function' places this question in the top-results (helping others).  But my main reason for posting this comment with good intentions to you is: 'webaps' change! Thus the majority of answers and questions on this site are valid only in a 'specific moment in time'.  Secondly: 'applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet' equals what? google,twitter,facebook only? this subsection on steckexchange is (at the moment) clearly called 'webapps'/webapplications..

Comment: I was reacting to flags on the question - and took a judgement that as the problem had a definite cause which has now been resolved it won't happen again. I'm happy to reopen the question this time, but if it gains more flags/close votes I can't make the same promise for other moderators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please clear your cache, we've updated some static files.

Comment: That works, now there is also line-numbering! PS, thank you for the very nice chat on irc!!!